# How to imshow a transparent image with background over background image

Tags: matlab, rotation

i want plot streeing wheel rotating on an instrument board image, to car streeing wheel simulation.

Making the background of the handle transparent has already been successful and i was try imshow image on the instrument board image using [hold on].

```
I = imread('audi_steering.PNG');
for i =1:10

    IY= imread('2016_Audi_A6_30T_instrument_cluster.png');
    imshow(IY);
    hold on;
    I_a=imrotate(I,i,'crop');
    h=imshow(I_a);

    alphadata = I_a<200;
    set(h,'AlphaData',alphadata(:,:,1));

end
```

Instead of rotating only the steering wheel drawn on the dashboard image, the dashboard image of the area where the steering wheel were drawn was also partially rotated.

image is like under link.(i can not upload image...)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5AKEhYs-kwL-diZc3SRmSqlOz3N4mlL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `set(h,'AlphaData'...` with `imshow` I think it's meant to be used with graphs, not images.

You better change the RGB pixel values of the image, and display the modified image.

The following code sample copy image `IY` into temporary image `J`, then copy the elements from `I_a` where `alphadata` = `0`.

Remark: the code works only if `IY` and `I_a` have the same size and dimensions.

```
IY = imread('2016_Audi_A6_30T_instrument_cluster.png');

for i = 1:10
    I_a = imrotate(I, i, 'crop');
    alphadata = I_a < 200;
    J = IY; %Copy IY to temporary image J
    J(~alphadata) = I_a(~alphadata); %Replace elements in J where alphadata = 0
    imshow(J);
    pause(1); %Pause between loops
end
```